# PHP ImageColorAllocate return values

Tags: php, gd

I have the following code to set 2 colours:

```
$_colours = array(
    0 => array(
        'r' => 255,
        'g' => 0,
        'b' => 0
    ),
    1 => array(
        'r' => 0,
        'g' => 255,
        'b' => 0
    )
);

$col[0] = ImageColorAllocate($base_image,$_colours[0]['r'],$_colours[0]['g'],$_colours[0]['b']);
$col[1] = ImageColorAllocate($base_image,$_colours[1]['r'],$_colours[1]['g'],$_colours[1]['b']);
```

However, `$col[0]` and `$col[1]` return `0` and `1` respectively, and instead of being red and green, I actually get black and white. I'm under the impression these should return a number for that colour, rather than 1/0.

Furthermore, I can change these `r/g/b` values to almost anything else I still get the same return values.

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: [`imagecolorallocate`](https://php.net/manual/function.imagecolorallocate.php) returns a `color identifier`. Just treat it as it is.

Comment: can you post code for `$base_image` ?

Comment: Sorry, missed something important in the question; the colour that is actually used in the generated image is black and white, whereas I'm trying to use red and green.

Comment: $base_image is the return value of ImageCreate(200, 200)

Answer (score 0):

`imageColorAllocate` returns a `color identifier` or `FALSE` if the allocation failed.

What your array holds should be *resources* (identifiers), not colors as such.

try:

```
imagesetpixel($base_image,5,5,$col[0]);
```

that should use the *identifier* to draw a pixel with your color.